# Does RFC 5322 allow reply-to header without any actual e-mail address? If so, what is its semantic?

Tags: email, reply, rfc5322

[Section 3.6.2 of RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) defines the *reply-to* header as:

```
reply-to        =   "Reply-To:" address-list CRLF
```

Where *address-list* is defined at [section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4). When unfolding the ABNF grammar, I find that *address-list* can consist of nothing but `phrase ":" ";"` (*phrase* being defined at [section 3.2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.5)). So it boils down to you being able to add a *reply-to* header that does not contains any actual e-mail address.

The RFC states:

> When the "Reply-To:" field is present, it indicates the address(es) to which the author of the message suggests that replies be sent.

Even if it is only a suggestion, it seems rather strange that I can suggest to someone to reply to an address I name but don't specify.

Am I missing something here? How should I interpret such a construction?

Comment: To me, it would seem logical to treat an empty `Reply-To` header as an indication that the message should not be replied to.

Comment: There is a feature in Outlook, possibly respected by GMail: https://www.technipages.com/outlook-disable-email-forwarding - it's also for "NoReplyAll" and "NoReply" options. I don't know if it's some proprietary hack, or a standarized way (e.g. Headers) to mark a message as "no reply".

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have discovered an oversight in the spec.  Nice!

If you read the rest of [Section 3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4), you find this (emphasis mine):

> When it is desirable to treat several
> mailboxes as a single unit (i.e., in a
> distribution list), the group
> construct can be used.  The group
> construct allows the sender to
> indicate a named group of recipients.
> This is done by giving a display name
> for the group, followed by a colon,
> followed by a comma-separated list of
> **any number of mailboxes (including
> zero and one)**, and ending with a
> semicolon. **Because the list of
> mailboxes can be empty, using the
> group construct is also a simple way
> to communicate to recipients that the
> message was sent to one or more named
> sets of recipients, without actually
> providing the individual mailbox
> address for any of those recipients.**

This makes sense in the context of (e.g.) To or CC, but not (e.g.) From or Reply-To.  They got this right for "From" by specifying it as a mailbox-list, but they seem to have botched it for Reply-To.

It looks like they should have made Reply-To a mailbox-list instead of an address-list.  Might be worth trying to contact the IETF working group to point out the error.

[update]

I have submitted an erratum against RFC 5322 for this issue:

http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?eid=2816

Let's see what they do with it.

Comment: Erratum has been rejected.

Comment: Update: The IETF decided in March 2013 to go the other way with the [RFC 6854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6854), namely proposing to make `from = "From:" (mailbox-list / address-list) CRLF`. The motivation: «The use cases for the "From:" field have evolved. There are numerous instances of automated systems that wish to send email but cannot handle replies, and a "From:" field with no usable addresses would be extremely useful for that purpose.»